R Class Method Without Object Creation
In R Reference class, it seems a class object must be created before using any of its methods. Is there a way to avoid object creation, like in Python, at least for cases which the reference class has no fields ?
MyClass <- setRefClass("MyClass",
    fields = list(),
    methods = list(
        hello_world = function(){
            print("Hello, world!")
        }
    )
)

#MyClass$hello_world() #gives error
obj <- MyClass$new()
obj$hello_world()


This sounds like an XY problem. In this case you should just create a function. Can you provide a bit more context about what you're trying to do? I've never needed or wanted a class method or static method equivalent in R. Also I would use R6 rather than RC, as it's just more mature, lighter weight and basically better. I don't know if you can do this in R6 though as I've never tried.

No. My plan is to write several static classes of helper functions and call its methods. It would take too many files if I just separate functions by file.

You can have multiple functions per file. If your concern is not cluttering up the global environment, what about a list of functions, or an environment containing all the functions?

So static classes is not the way to go in R? I am really supposed to write files which contains nothing but functions or list of functions?

I'm not sure the second point follows from the first. You can define objects using R6 or S4 or S3. You can create packages. You can write and call C++ code. I have just never needed static methods in R and can't think of a situation that requires them. I'm open to hearing one though.

I got no error when I ran your code and I got the expected result. Furthermore, assigning the vale of that function call gave me the Hello,world! character value. You should have included full error message and a complete description of your  setup.

@IRTFM I think the line that can't be run is the one commented out - i.e. calling the method without instantiating an object of the class.

The usual R way to do what you want is what @SamR suggested:  just make a list of functions.  For example:
MyFunctions <- list(
  hello_world = function(){
            print("Hello, world!")
        }
)

MyFunctions$hello_world()

# or
with(MyFunctions, hello_world())

# or 
MyEnv <- list2env(MyFunctions)
MyEnv$hello_world() 

There are some differences between environments and lists that make environments preferable, so I'd often choose the last of these (though I'd probably create it differently).
If you want two or more functions that know about each other, you can do it like this:
fns <- local({
  fn1 <- function() fn2()
  fn2 <- function() print("this is fn2")
  environment()
})

fns$fn1()

